# Which verb tense "has been done" fit?

Tags: tense

I'm seeing sentences using `have/has been done`, is It Present Perfect? Because Present Perfect is formed [has/have + past participle].

Like:

> This has been done in America, but only at practices with a patient-list of 50,000 or more.

There's two past participle.

Comment: It's a present perfect passive construction. The perfect is constructed from  a form of *HAVE* followed by a past participle, the passive is constructed from a form of *BE* followed past participle, so the perfect passive is a form of *HAVE* followed by *been* (the past participle of *BE*) followed by the past participle of the lexical verb: in this case *done* as the past participle of *do*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the equivalent of past pluperfect in a the passive voice.

Try it in the active voice first, and it becomes a little easier to see.

I do it. (present)
I have done it. (past perfect)  It is now over and done with.
I had done it. (past pluperfect) Even in the past, it was over and done with.

Back to the passive voice.
It is being done. (present)
It has been done. (equivalent of past perfect)
It had been done (equivalent of past pluperfect)

Comment: Do you have a good link with explanation more detailed about it? I've never heard it :x

Comment: *Has been done* would usually be regarded as present perfect. *Had been done would usually be regarded as past perfect*.